# Netbeans can't access GitHub

Tags: ssh, 15.04, netbeans, github

Ubuntu 15.04. Netbeans can`t access github. I've try terminal. it says that ssh key ip something... I've genarate new ssh-key, added to github, to my ssh. So via terminal it work but, via netbeans still not.
I`am really sorry if my question is little bit blur, i`am just in hurry by means of work....
So the question is how to solve netbeans 8.0.2 problem with connection to github.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start netbeans in a terminal, any error messages? Give me a ping with @A.B.

Answer (score 0):

You've provided currently no further information or error messages. Therefore here is the basic procedure.

Clone a repository via:

```
Team » Git » Clone
```

[image]

You need:

- User name: `git`
- Your private key file

Comment: Thank for responde. I was in a hurry,that is why i miss details.

Comment: I've try it(with key file) but no result. I`ve downgrade to Kubuntu 14.04 and happy with everything.